# Pass arguments from command line in Perl

Tags: perl

I have written the Perl code and trying to pass the command line arguments and not getting expected output.

Here is my code:

```
my ($buildno, $appname, $ver) = @ARGV;

print values \@ARGV;

$Artifact_name = "flora-$appname-$ver";

mkdir "$target_dir/$Artifact_name";'
```

When I run the Perl script `perl scripts\perl\test.pl  "MobileApp",  %ver%`, I am getting the following output: `flora-MobileApp-`

And the log message is showing

> 'Use of uninitialized value $ver in concatenation (.) or string at
>   Jscripts\perl\test.pl line 31 (#3)'.

`%ver%` is the environment variable and its value is `1.0.1.23`.

I am expecting the output `flora-MobileApp-1.0.1.23`.

Comment: Please tell us, how you are running the script?

Comment: I am runnign the script in batch command line . perl scripts\perl\test.pl  "MobileApp",  %ver%

Comment: How many parameters are you passing to the script, and how many are you expecting in the script?

Comment: @Сухой27,I am passing 2 arguments. from the above code,$appname, $ver. i am callign the script like this with command line arguments. perl scripts\perl\test.pl "MobileApp", %ver%.  $appname is Mobileapp and $ver is %ver%(1.0.1.23);

Comment: third parameter is null `$ver`

Comment: @ssr1012, Are you asking a question, if yes $ver is not null it has the value.

Comment: Passing 2 and expecting 3, leaves `$ver` undefined..

Comment: @Сухой27, I am not getting can you please explain with example?

Comment: you are running the script as `batch` file

Comment: `my ($buildno, $appname, $ver)` - how many variables do you see here?

Comment: Moreover you should separate command line arguments by space only, not comma.

Comment: @melpomene,3 variables and i am passing 2 and 3 variables. I don't want pass 1st variable.

Comment: @jira,I removed comma and rerun it and now the output is like flora-1.0.1.23-. it is taking 3 rd argument not displaying 2nd argument. any advise.

Comment: ... do you not understand that 2 and 3 are not the same number?

Comment: yes, those are not the same. If you know the how to pass please give any example.

Comment: `perl scripts\perl\test.pl not_interested_in_first "MobileApp"  %ver%`

Comment: @Сухой27 , perfect it is working now as expected. Thanks

Comment: I've removed the `perl-module` tag. There's nothing about Perl module's in this question.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that perl doesn't pass the script name to `@ARGV`. It get's passed to the special variable `$0` instead and `@ARGV` is populated with the remaining parameters in the command. The perlvar page has more info about it: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html. I know there are a number of windows utilities where the script name does get passed in as an argument so that may be where the 3 vs 2 variable confusion is coming from.

Answer (score 4):

So you run the program like this:

```
perl scripts\perl\test.pl  "MobileApp",  %ver%
```

And then, within the program you are accessing the command line arguments like this:

```
my ($buildno, $appname, $ver) = @ARGV;
```

There's an obvious mismatch here. You are passing in two arguments, but expecting three. You will end up with "MobileApp" in `$buildno` and the contents of `%ver%` in `$appname`. Your last variable, `$ver`, will remain undefined.

If you want three variables to be set, then you need to pass three arguments.

And, if you wanted to investigate this, then surely it would have been simple to print out the values of your three variables?

The "fix" is to pass another value as the first command line option so that the parameters line up with the variables.

```
perl scripts\perl\test.pl something_else "MobileApp"  %ver%
```

But I'm fascinated to hear what level of confusion makes this problem hard to debug.

**Update:** Another option (as PerlDuck has reminded me in a comment) would be to fix the code to only expect two arguments.

```
my ($appname, $ver) = @ARGV;
```

Comment: Given that the OP has _"written the Perl code"_ I think the apparent solution would be to assign only two arguments to the variables as in `my ($appname, $ver) = @ARGV;` and leave `$buildno` alone or assign whatever else to it.